# Prolog family tree

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a family tree program in Prolog for my homework. This is a part of the code.

```
/** a sample fact **/
parents(someone, someoneelse, child).

/** are M and F parents of the children in the given list? **/
parents(M,F,[]) :- parents(M,F,_).
parents(M,F,[First|Rest]) :- parents(M,F,First), parents(M,F,Rest).

/** are M and F parents? **/
parents(M,F) :- parents(M,F,_).
```

When I use a query that matches the fact, above code works.

```
   [trace] 25 ?- parents(someone,someoneelse).
       Call: (6) parents(someone, someoneelse) ? creep
       Call: (7) parents(someone, someoneelse, _G586) ? creep
       Exit: (7) parents(someone, someoneelse, child) ? creep
       Exit: (6) parents(someone, someoneelse) ? creep
    true 
    .
```

But when I try this:

```
[trace] 26 ?- parents(aa, bb).
   Call: (6) parents(aa, bb) ? creep
   Call: (7) parents(aa, bb, _G541) ? creep
   Call: (8) parents(aa, bb, _G541) ? creep
   Call: (9) parents(aa, bb, _G541) ? creep
   Call: (10) parents(aa, bb, _G541) ? 
...
```

it doesn't work, it enters an infinite loop. What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: I've changed the code as such:

```
/** a sample fact **/
parents(someone, someoneelse, child).

/** are M and F parents of the children in the given list? **/
parents(M,F,[]).
parents(M,F,[First|Rest]) :- parents(M,F,First), parents(M,F,Rest).

/** are M and F parents? **/
parents(M,F) :- parents(M,F,A), not(A=[]).
```

Now what I get is this:

```
[trace] 3 ?- parents(a,b).
   Call: (6) parents(a, b) ? creep
   Call: (7) parents(a, b, _G514) ? creep
   Exit: (7) parents(a, b, []) ? creep
^  Call: (7) not([]=[]) ? creep
^  Fail: (7) not(user: ([]=[])) ? creep
   Redo: (7) parents(a, b, _G514) ? creep
   Call: (8) parents(a, b, _G508) ? creep
   Exit: (8) parents(a, b, []) ? creep
   Call: (8) parents(a, b, _G509) ? creep
   Exit: (8) parents(a, b, []) ? creep
   Exit: (7) parents(a, b, [[]]) ? creep
^  Call: (7) not([[]]=[]) ? creep
^  Exit: (7) not(user: ([[]]=[])) ? creep
   Exit: (6) parents(a, b) ? creep
true 
.
```

I don't understand why it goes to redo after fail now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the search. Prolog will go through all the rules and find a match. If it matches, then it will go through the expansion and repeat the process.

The 2nd line is the cause of inf loop, since don't care (from the last rule) is mapped to [].

If you want to find out whether a pair is parent of any child or not, you just remove the 2 middle rules:

```
parents(M,F,[]) :- parents(M,F,_).
parents(M,F,[First|Rest]) :- parents(M,F,First), parents(M,F,Rest).
```

Comment: What do you mean with not declaring it?

Comment: If you don't declare the fact, prolog cannot produce an answer. Well, that is what I can tell from the information given.

Comment: parents(someone, someoneelse, child).

Doesn't this line declare the fact?

Comment: I edited my answer, I am not sure if that is what is required, though.

Comment: Those two predicates are for checking if a given list of children is in fact the children of specific parents. Like : "?- parents(a,b,[c,d]). So that is totally different.

Comment: But you are right, when I remove those middle lines, it works. I don't understand why though.

Comment: I explained in the post. Expand parents(trash, garbage) by 5th line becomes parents(trash, garbage, []), then it go through the top and found a match in the 2nd line, which keeps the same thing, and it go through from top again, found match in 2nd line... The process becomes an inf. loop.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If it finds a match why doesn't it return the result?

Comment: "Call: (7) parents(aa, bb, _G541) ? creep" after this why doesn't it just return false as there is no such fact?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11531/discussion-between-nhahtdh-and-hattenn)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you are confusing two different predicates into one:

```
/** a sample fact **/
parents(someone, someoneelse, child).

/** are M and F parents of any child? **/
parents(M,F) :- parents(M,F,_).

/** are M and F parents of the children in the given list? **/
parents_of_all_children(M,F,[]).
parents_of_all_children(M,F,[First|Rest]) :-
    parents(M,F,First), parents_of_all_children(M,F,Rest).
```

Then, your queries make sense:

```
?- parents(someone, someoneelse, C).
C = child.
%-- someone & someoneelse have child "child"

?- parents(A, B).
A = someone,
B = someoneelse.
%-- all possible parent pairs out there

?- parents(aa, bb).
false.
%-- do "aa" & "bb" form a parents pair?
```